# Three-Way Diff in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, diff

I have three SQL tables (`A`, `B`, and `C`), representing three different version of a dataset. I want to devise an SQL query whose effect is to extract the ids of rows/tuples whose values are different in all three tables. (Two records are different if there exists a field where the records do not share the same value.) For simplicity, let's just assume that `A`, `B`, and `C` each have `N` records with record ids ranging from 1 to `N`, so for every id from 1 to `N`, there is a record in each table with that ID.

What might be the most efficient way to do this in SQL? One way would be to do something like

```
(SELECT id FROM 
((SELECT * FROM A EXCEPT SELECT * FROM B) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM C)) result)
EXCEPT
(SELECT id FROM
((SELECT * FROM A) INTERSECT (SELECT * FROM B)) result2)
```

Basically what I've done above is first found the ids of records where the version in `A` differs from the version of `B` and from the version in `C` (in the first two lines of the SQL query I've written). What's left is to filter out the ids of record where the version in `B` matches the version in `C` (which is done in the last two lines). But this seems horribly inefficient; is there a better, more concise way?

Note: I'm using PostgreSQL syntax here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
select id, 
       a.id is null as "missing in a",
       b.id is null as "missing in b",
       c.id is null as "missing in c",
       a is distinct from b as "a and b different",
       a is distinct from c as "a and c different",
       b is distinct from c as "b and c different"
from a 
  full join b using (id)
  full join c using (id) 
where a is distinct from b
   or b is distinct from c
   or a is distinct from c
```

The `id` column is assumed to be a primary (or unique) key.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f13c63347ecd6afa8a3af4a5496cfd1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `group by` and `having` as follows:

```
select id from
(select * from A
union select * from B
union select * from C)
group by id
-- use characters that you know will not appear in this columns for concat
having count(distinct column1 || '#~#' || column2 || '#~#' || column3) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I’m not sure if this works however. Consider a tuple with id = 0 whose non-id fields are (1,2,3) in A, (1,2,4) in B, and (2,2,3) in C. Then count(distinct column) is strictly less than 3 for each column, but this tuple should be identified.

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer. Please check. It was not clear from question.

Comment: I apologize. Unfortunately this doesn’t work either (again the question may have not been clear) because this would only filter out the tuples which are the same in each version. But what I would want is for it not to include a tuple which is (1,2,3) in A, (1,2,3) in B, and (4,5,6) in C, because the A and B versions are the same. Basically, I want to find the tuples whose A and B versions are different, B and C versions are different, and A and C versions are different. It should be the same logic as three way diff logic, if you are familiar with that. Thanks again!

Comment: I think simply `having count(*) = 3` will do the trick.